# Class LumenServiceProvider Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

While using `Lumen 5.5` with `Tymon JWT Auth 0.5.12`, I cannot generate secret key.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider' not found
```

I followed this method described by Tymon for Lumen specifically.
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1102

Comment: Have u added Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider class in config/app.php

Comment: No, I haven't added. Can you tell me how to add?

Comment: Sorry..my bad, i mean in bootstrap/app.php

Comment: well it's fixed using `^1.0@dev` version of JWT-Auth. Thank You so much

Comment: okay, that means it was versioning issue else you can reffer this link as well http://www.akaita.com/post/json-web-token-authentication-for-lumen-5-tymon-jwt-auth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reffer this link - 
`http://www.akaita.com/post/json-web-token-authentication-for-lumen-5-tymon-jwt-auth/`

Hope this will help you.